# Output a watched Visual Studio variable to a file

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Is there a way in Visual Studio (2008 if it matters) that I can, in debug/break mode, write the contents of a variable to a text/XML file?

The scenario is that I have a long process running in debug and I have realised too late that I haven't logged enough detail about the events that the process has been monitoring, but fortunately a history is still available within a variable in the code.

I could trawl through the tens of thousands of items in this list, but it's not going to persist once I hit stop on the application ... there is no obvious context option for this, but is there any way, a better way than manual? Or is there no hope and I just need to hit stop, re-tool the logging function and run the thing again?

Aside from trying to hit a breakpoint, modify the code and re-write to make a better logger, is there a way of not losing that in-memory data?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

One way to do it would be to use the immediate window (menu *Debug* -> *Windows* -> *Immediate*). In the window that appears you can use the "?" to query the value of a variable.

Assuming your history variable is a string you view its contents by typing the following in the immediate window:

```
?history
```

You could copy and paste the output from there into a text file or alternatively ask Visual Studio to log all command window output. To do this type:

```
>log "c:\test.log"
>? history
>log off
```

`Log` is an alias for `Tools.LogCommandWindowOutput` and accepts the following parameters:

```
Tools.LogCommandWindowOutput [filename] [/on|/off] [/overwrite]
```

Check out the MSDN article *[Log Command Window Output Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x72c7xc8.aspx)* for more information.

Comment: Remember to add a space in between "?" and "history"

Comment: identifier "history" is undefined --> i get this error

Comment: @AlphaGoku "history" is a variable name so will depend on your context. This is the variable containing the data you wish to log to disk.

Answer (score 4):

I think that my answer is pretty much the same as JamesPickrell's, but from the Immediate Window you could also do something like this:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("c:\temp.txt",history,True)
```

This would output the content of the "history" variable to a file called c:\temp.txt.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [Richard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1333693/134761), this is working for me.

`System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\Temp\temp.txt", myVar);`

Make sure that `C:\Temp` exists.

The reason for writing to a folder and not to the root `C:\` is to avoid `UnauthorizedAccessException` when not running Visual Studio as administrator.

Comment: `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes` is available only if you are debugging C#.  It won't work if you are trying to debug some other language such as C++.

Answer (score 3):

I found useful/demonstrative/shareable to save the variable as a json string to the file. From Immediate Window enter the following:

```
string jsonedVariable = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(VARIABLE);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\FILENAME.json", jsonedVariable);
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure from which version it's supported, but you can simply put it in the `WATCH` window, then right-click copy past wherever you want.