# Can i print the information of the locals window in my application visual studio?

Tags: debugging, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging, vs-extensibility

I am wondering, if there is any way that let us print all the variables and their values that are displayed on locals window.

To be clearer ,I do want to create a application that works same as locals window in the visual studio during a process execution. Can I know how it could be acheived? Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Not found the possible solution for it. If you just want to get the variable value, one workaround is that you could use the immediate window instead of local window. Or you could customer Debugging watch window to output the view lists you want to get with native extension.

[Output a watched Visual Studio variable to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333317/output-a-watched-visual-studio-variable-to-a-file?rq=1)

But not found the way to achieve it using the local windows.

I help you submit a feature request to the product team here:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/30957622-can-i-print-the-information-of-the-locals-window-i

If possible, you could also vote and add your comment there.