# How to enlarge visual studio watch output window

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging, dump

I am using visual studio 2017 for debugging C++ project,
I am using the "Watch" for dumping content of Objects, I can see the output in visual studio window (a black window that opens on debugging).

if I dump a too much large object (with too much content), I cant see all of the output, when I scroll up in the black window it reaches a point where I cant scroll more but there is more data up that I want to see.

is there a way to enlarge the stack of it or instead dump to a file?

I saw this solution:

[Output a watched Visual Studio variable to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333317/output-a-watched-visual-studio-variable-to-a-file)

but it just dumps the Object type and didn't dump its content (I use my own dump function to dump the content)

in the picture: can't scroll more up

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Right-click the window title and choose "Defaults" and change the buffer size to be over 9000 lines tall and 120 columns wide, then restart your application.